# Loading iframe in php giving error

Tags: php, iframe

If I don't include the iframe in following line, the page works fine. Otherwise my other element in page are not getting loaded.

I can only share this chunk code at the moment :

```
foreach ( $video_rows as $row) {
    echo " <div class='video_row'> <iframe id = 'list_player' allowFullScreen src='https://player.synq.fm/embed/$row->video_id?autostart=true&mute=true&repeat=true&skin.active=4E579E'></div>";
}
```

There is no js errors in console and if I remove iframe, the whole page loads fine.

Comment: You forgot an 'end' iframe: </iframe>

Answer (score 0):

I missed a closing iframe tag , noob mistake from my side